# Unterminated string literal when trying to append HTML from a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wysiwyg

I have a page to create articles. I am storing HTML Markup that is generated by the article WYSIWYG editor into a MySQL database.

My html is turned into HTML entities just before I insert it into the database like this:

```
htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('card_content'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false)
```

The data is stored in the database like this:

```
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;Where do you work? &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;What do you do?&nbsp; &lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;What position do you have?&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

I also need to update the article content and mark up. To do this I have an "edit article" page where I have to display the article markup back into the WYSIWYG editor which is an Iframe that has `designMode = 'on'`.

I am appending the decoded HTML back into the WYSIWYG Iframe using the following code:

```
function enableEditMode(){
    card_content.document.designMode = 'On';
    $('iframe[name=card_content]').contents().find('body').append("<?php echo addslashes(html_entity_decode($card->card_html)); ?>");
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

This is because the appended HTML is on many lines...

[image]

**Question:**

I have all my break spaces in place so I have no idea why there is white space... How do I make sure my HTML is just in a single line without white spcace? And by extension, is there a better way to append HTML into the Iframe?

Comment: Do `<? echo trim(addslashes(html_` and test again. Or lets say: in javascript when you bind values to an varaiable, the content MUST be in one line and does not have line-breaks in it!!

Comment: You could use a php function (say `str_replace`) to remove all the line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output a string from php to javascript, you should use `json_encode()` instead. Note that you should remove the quotes in javascript as well as `json_encode()` will quote the string:

```
$('iframe[name=card_content]').contents().find('body').append(<?php echo json_encode(html_entity_decode($card->card_html)); ?>);
                                                              ^ no quotes here
```

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions If you encode a string with `json_encode()`, you will get a string wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I missed the `html_entity_decode()` but for the rest I think this is what the OP needs; the php string correctly passed to javascript.

Comment: OK, i got your use of `json_encode`, but i thing that not the best solution.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I think it's the safest way to pass data from php to javascript; you don't want to manually escape every character that can cause problems in javascript.

Comment: I would hide the content and show if it is needed, without use of `append()`. But, lets him get it done, with your solution ;-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I didn't really check the logic, just the passing of the information :-)

Comment: The edited post works like a charm! Thanks so much Jeroen, never saw that tip about json_encoding the HTML in my research. Very handy tip!